# Advanced subtraction between two lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

Quick Example:

situation 1:

```
lt1 = [1,2,3,3,3,4]
lt2 = [1,2,3]
diff = lt1 - lt2
diff = [3,3,4]
```

situation2:

```
lt1 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,4]
lt2 = [1,2,3]
diff = lt1 - lt2 * 2
diff = [3,3,4]
```

I finished coding situation 1, but have no idea for 2, could anyone help me create a function fit all situations?

Subtract N times the smaller list from the larger list as a diff list.

Here is my code:

```
dif = [i for i in lt1 if i not in lt2 or lt2.remove(i)]
```

For situation2:

```
output = [1,2,3,3,3,4]
```

Comment: Does "subtract N times" mean "remove up to N instances of elements in second list"?

Comment: N means how many small list in big list. 
In situation2, N = 2, because lt1 has 2 "1,2,3". 
If lt1 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1], then N = 3.

Comment: You should add the code you have for situation 1 and people might be able to explain where it falls short.

Comment: Loop two times through your solution for the simple version (situation 1). There might be a problem with this approach, but I don't know since you didn't provide your code (yet).

Comment: I have added my code, thanks for reminding.

Comment: So the order of the elements does not matter? Because with `lt1 = [3,2,1,3,3,4]` you also get `[3,3,4]` as a result. If that is correct then you can simply do `lt2 = lt2 * 2` in the line before your code.

Comment: I will sort 2 lists, so i think order does not matter. Thanks for your suggestion, but i dont think I can simply do `*2`, because situation is changing, my lt1 and lt2 are also changing, i prefer create a functino, and using that function in my project.

Comment: I have a feeling that we misunderstand each other. If you want a function then why can't the body of your function be `lt2 = lt2 * 2`, followed by `return [i for i in lt1 if i not in lt2 or lt2.remove(i)]`? Of course the `2` could also be a parameter of that function.

Comment: Yeah i got your point now.

Comment: By the way, this `or lt2.remove(i)` in your code is a pretty clever trick.

Answer (score 1):

In the second attempt, you're comparing it only with `l2`, whereas you're expecting it to compare with `l2*2`.

You can update `l2` with `l2*2` and run the same snippet, it'll work.

```
lt1 = [1,2,3,3,3,4]
lt2 = [1,2,3]

dif = [i for i in lt1 if i not in lt2 or lt2.remove(i)]
print(dif)

lt1 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,4]
lt2 = [1,2,3]

lt2 = lt2 * 2
dif = [i for i in lt1 if i not in lt2 or lt2.remove(i)]
print(dif)
```

Output:

```
[3, 3, 4]
[3, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you wouldn't want to modify your input data to produce an output.  You can do so by adding an extra nesting level in the comprehension to get a (multiplied) copy of lt2:

```
lt1   = [1,2,3,3,3,4]
lt2   = [1,2,3]
N     = 1
diff  = [i for r in [lt2*N] for i in lt1 if i not in r or r.remove(i)]

print(diff) # [3, 3, 4]

lt1   = [1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,4]
lt2   = [1,2,3]
N     = 2
diff  = [i for r in [lt2*N] for i in lt1 if i not in r or r.remove(i)]

print(diff) # [3, 3, 4]
```

[EDIT] using Counter

If your numbers in lt2 are distinct and what you need to do is remove N occurrences of them from lt1, you can use the Counter class from collections.  It should also run faster for large lists:

```
from collections import Counter
rem   = Counter(dict.fromkeys(lt2,N))
diff  = [i for i in lt1 if rem.subtract((i,)) or rem[i]<0]

print(diff)
[3, 3, 4]
```

If you do have duplicates, you'll need to feed Counter directly with the repeated list:

```
from collections import Counter
rem   = Counter(lt2*N))
diff  = [i for i in lt1 if rem.subtract((i,)) or rem[i]<0]
```

Comment: i am thinking is there any way to optimize this code, not input the N manually whereas using for loop or some other ways find matched N.